# Brostrend AC1200 wifi suddenly stopped working

Tags: wireless

I followed the instructions here (https://blog.danielscrivano.com/installing-rtl8812au-on-linux-for-wireless-dual-band-usb-adapters/) to set up the Brostrend AC1200 wifi and it was working well. For some reason it no longer connects. Any ideas on how to fix this?

I tried the instruction again (apart from re-cloning) and I get the following error:

```
geoff@geoff-System-Product-Name:~$ cd rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux
geoff@geoff-System-Product-Name:~/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux$ make
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.10.0-33-generic/build M=/home/geoff/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-33-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/geoff/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.o
/home/geoff/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:1695:22: error: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
  .ndo_select_queue = rtw_select_queue,
                      ^
/home/geoff/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:1695:22: note: (near initialization for ‘rtw_netdev_ops.ndo_select_queue’)
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:294: recipe for target '/home/geoff/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/geoff/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.o] Error 1
Makefile:1524: recipe for target '_module_/home/geoff/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/geoff/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-33-generic'
Makefile:1131: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

Here's the lsusb and dkms status:

```
geoff@geoff-System-Product-Name:~$ lsusb
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. M105 Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:8812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8812AU 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WLAN Adapter
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

geoff@geoff-System-Product-Name:~$ dkms status
bbswitch, 0.8, 4.10.0-32-generic, x86_64: installed
bbswitch, 0.8, 4.10.0-33-generic, x86_64: installed
bbswitch, 0.8, 4.10.0-35-generic, x86_64: installed
bbswitch, 0.8, 4.4.0-93-generic, x86_64: installed
bbswitch, 0.8, 4.4.0-96-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-375, 375.66, 4.10.0-32-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-375, 375.66, 4.10.0-33-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-375, 375.66, 4.10.0-35-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-375, 375.66, 4.4.0-93-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-375, 375.66, 4.4.0-96-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 5.0.40, 4.10.0-32-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 5.0.40, 4.10.0-33-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 5.0.40, 4.10.0-35-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 5.0.40, 4.4.0-93-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 5.0.40, 4.4.0-96-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Comment: Do it again. After each kernel upgrade you need to re-install the driver. Or look for a DKMS solution.

Comment: I get an error:
git clone https://github.com/scrivy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux.git
fatal: destination path 'rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux' already exists and is not an empty directory.

Or if skip that step and go to the next steps (make) I get this error:
error: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
  .ndo_select_queue = rtw_select_queue,

Comment: You don't need to clone it again. Skip this step.

Comment: Please don't post this to comments. [Edit] your question.

Comment: thanks @Pilot6 I've copied all the lines to the question.

Comment: Now you have the 4.10 kernel, the driver doesn't build for it. Please also add output of `lsusb` and `dkms status`. I'll see what can be done. Meanwhile you can boot with a previous kernel.

Comment: thanks again for the info @Pilot6, as you may have guessed this is my first computer build and first time using Linux. I've added the lsusb and dkms status as you requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your kernel got upgraded to 4.10.

You need to install the driver from `zesty` repo to build against the 4.10 kernel.

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/r/rtl8812au/rtl8812au-dkms_4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg-0ubuntu5_all.deb
sudo apt install rtl8812au-dkms_4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg-0ubuntu5_all.deb
```

Comment: a belated thanks @Pilot6. My wifi is back up and running thanks to you.